# Node.js React JWT Login

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication, jwt, token

It's ok, I got my Token on Node.js, I tested with Postman. 
But I want to recuperate my Token in React with localStorage.
I don't understand why, but it doesn't work.
Browser toolbox says "TypeError: this is undefined".

When I try with "bind", browser say nothing. No error but
my localStorage is empty.
For the second case, PreventDefault() doesn't work, i replaced it by persist().

**Login.js**

```
class Login extends Component {

  state = {
    email:"",
    password:"",
  }

async postLogin(e){

  await this.setState({
    [e.target.name]: e.target.value
  })

    e.preventDefault(e);
    const login = {
        email:this.state.email,
        password:this.state.password
    };

  await axios.post("http://localhost:7777/api/users/login", login)
        .then((response) => {
            const {token} = response.data;
            localStorage.setItem("token", token)
            this.props.history.push("/articles")
        })

        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        })
}


  render(){

    return(
        <div className="containerSign">
          <h1>Connecte toi</h1>
          <form onSubmit={this.postLogin}>
            <input className="inputFormSign" type="email" placeholder="Email"/>
            <input className="inputFormSign" type="password" placeholder="Mot de passe"/>
            <button className="btnFormSign" type="submit">Envoyer</button>
          </form>
        </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Login;
```

**Login.js with bind**

```
postLogin = this.postLogin.bind(this);

async postLogin(e){

  await this.setState({
    [e.target.name]: e.target.value
  })

    e.persist(e);
    const login = {
        email:this.state.email,
        password:this.state.password
    };

  await axios.post("http://localhost:7777/api/users/login", login)
        .then((response) => {
            const {token} = response.data;
            localStorage.setItem("token", token)
            this.props.history.push("/articles")
        })

        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        })
}


  render(){

    return(
        <div className="containerSign">
          <h1>Connecte toi</h1>
          <form onSubmit={this.postLogin}>
            <input className="inputFormSign" type="email" placeholder="Email"/>
            <input className="inputFormSign" type="password" placeholder="Mot de passe"/>
            <button className="btnFormSign" type="submit">Envoyer</button>
          </form>
        </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Login;
```

Comment: you should add lifecycle method like componentDidMount

Answer (score 0):

You should use [autobind decorator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/autobind-decorator) package to eradicate this issue!

Installation:

```
npm install --save autobind-decorator
```

Examples:

```
import autobind from 'autobind-decorator';

@autobind
class Component { }

// or

@autobind
method() {
  return this.value
}
```

note:

To use `ES7 decorators` you must install [babel-plugin-transform-decorators](http://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-decorators)

Answer (score 0):

You must [bind the method](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html), for example using [class property](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-class-properties/):

```
async postLogin = (e) => {
  ...
}
```